# JPA optimistic lock - setting @Version to entity class cause query to include VERSION as column

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, version, jpql

I'm using JPA Toplink Essential, Netbean6.8, GlassFish v3

In my Entity class I added `@Version annotation` to enable `optimistic locking` at transaction commit however after I added the annotation, **my query started including VERSION as column thus throwing SQL exception.**

None of this is mentioned in any tutorial I've seen so far. What could be wrong?

**Snippet**

```
public class MasatosanTest2 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "note")
    private String note;

    //here adding Version
    @Version
    int version;
```

query used:

```
SELECT m FROM MasatosanTest2 m

Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException
Call: SELECT id, username, note, VERSION FROM MasatosanTest2
```

Comment: It is normal. An optimistic lock requires a dedicated control column on the database side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add version as numeric column to your table. This column will be used for optimistic locking.

But I do prefer date field for optimistic locking, in that way you can track when that object has changed.

Comment: Ahh.. I see, like last modified date column??? So does JPA if lock is required, needs to have version (or alternative) column for every table?